# Why doesn't the depletion zone width in a MOS device increase when the applied voltage is over the threshold?

Tags: mosfet, semiconductors

When a positive voltage V is applied in a MOSCap, the depletion zone width will increase until the threshold voltage is reached. If the applied voltage is above the threshold voltage, the depletion layer will not increase in width.

What are the reasons for this behavior? Why, when over the threshold voltage, will the bands only bend slightly, leaving the depletion width unchanged?

EDIT:
What I don't understand is that the threshold is defined as the condition in which the density of electrons near the oxide is equal to the density of donors. In other words: I've applied a voltage which has caused the "conversion" of a p-type semiconductor into an n-type one. If I further increase the voltage more electrons will be collected under the oxide, but the depletion zone will not increase in width. Why not?

Comment: You should be aware that threshold voltage is defined differently by different groups.  I define the threshold voltage as where the channel is 1/2 drift and 1/2 diffusion.   The physicists like the version in your edit, but for undoped channels, we tend to use my first definition.

Answer (score 1):

Once the silicon is biased into strong inversion, the free-electron density at the surface is nearly an exponential function of the potential at the surface, so the surface potential changes little with increasing gate voltage after the inversion layer forms. The charge induced by the additional gate voltage is virtually all free-electron charge just below the oxide-silicon interface. Thus, the total potential drop across the depletion region and the depletion-layer width in the silicon are both relatively constant after the surface is inverted.

Source: Device Electronics for Integrated Circuits, R. Muller, T. Kamins.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider an N-channel MOSFET as shown below. We dope the substrate with the p-type material, which causes the silicon to have somewhat excess of what called holes. Now we are going to dope right beside the ends of dielectric layer with an n-type material, as you see below:

[image]

N-type dopants have excess of electrons. We dope highly these regions with n-type materials in such a way that they become highly conductive. Now we apply a positive voltage to the gate of the FET with respect to the p-type substrate. Now what this does is attract electrons from N-channel region and repel holes outward to the bulk silicon. If you keep increasing the gate voltage you'd attract more and more electrons until you have collected up all electrons. From now on, increasing gate voltage would have no effect on the width of the channel.

EDIT:

The region below the oxide layer is populated with a p-type material. Placing a **positive** charge on the gate would drive the **holes** away from the region below the oxide layer, leaving a depleted region that is insulating because no mobile holes remain. At the same time it attracts electrons from N+ regions, making a an inversion layer containing of electrons. Increasing the voltage on the gate leads to a higher electron density in the inversion layer.

The electrons come from the N+ regions. The n-type doping is made in such a way that after a certain voltage on the gate is reached you would get no more electrons. Therefore further increasing the gate voltage would have no effect whatsoever on the inversion layer width. In other words, you don't have any more free electrons to bring into the inversion layer.

Comment: The answer explain how DEMOSFET works. I was asking about a simple MOS capacitor composed only of Metal, Oxide and a p-Si bulk.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the picture. A DE-NMOS is the same as an E-NMOS except that it has a separate N-type channel formed within the substrate.

Comment: What I was saying is that you said that the threshold is reached when "you have collected up all electrons". But all the electron of what? All the electrons in conduction band of the bulk maybe?

Comment: I edited the question. Don't know if you're still stuck on that

Comment: The device I referring (I call it MOS capacitor, I don't know if there is a better name for that) has not the N+ regions. It is a simple p-Si bulk with a layer of oxide and a metal gate. If I apply a reverse tension, the holes are attracted toward the bulk terminal creating a depletion zone. If I further increase the voltage at a certain point holes are not more neutralized and electrons from the terminal flown under the oxide and form the inversion layer.
Why this "certain point" exists and why it is reached at the threshold voltage?

Comment: What you are describing is just a capacitor, but a weird one! You apply a voltage on either side of it. Think of an electrolytic. It has a safe operating voltage limit, exceeding which will burn out your capacitor. A MOS capacitor on its own is a simple capacitor. Not any useful. The concept of threshold voltage doesn't apply here. It's used for MOS devices.

Comment: The device I'm talkig about can be found here: http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~hu/Chenming-Hu_ch5.pdf
but maybe this is an idealization made to introduce MOSFET and actually the electrons came out from the N+ region as you said, even if these are not drawn.

Comment: What I said applies only to a MOSFET as a whole not the MOS capacitor part. I never studied in great detail the physics behind a MOSFET. Anyway, in the case of a MOS capacitor electrons are being induced below the oxide layer due to the positive charge placed on the gate. Much the same like a plane capacitor.